# Juniper EX4650 pass double tags on trunk interface

Tags: juniper-junos, juniper-ex

Example topology:

custA / custB > switch1 > EX4650 > switch2 > custA / custB

custA outer tag 101

custB outer tag 102

The EX4650 should allow any inner tag on both vlan 101 and 102.

Dot1Q tunnel ingress is happening on switch1 and switch2, the EX4650 just needs to bridge.

Inner tag is lost during forwarding.

Any thoughts on what needs changed to prevent the inner tags from being lost?

Ether-type of both tags is 0x8100

```
xe-0/0/0 {
    description "to switch1";
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            interface-mode trunk;
            vlan {
                members [ custA custB ];
            }
        }
    }
}

xe-0/0/1 {
    description "to switch2";
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            interface-mode trunk;
            vlan {
                members [ custA custB ];
            }
        }
    }
}

.......

custA {
    vlan-id 101;
}
custB {
    vlan-id 102;
}
```

Comment: Confirmed the switch is receiving both tags and forwarding out the other interface, but the inner tag is not present on egress.

Comment: So the payload is preserved, but the inner tag is stripped?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the Ethertype that is being used by switch 1/2 for the dot1q tag?  It will either be 0x8100, 0x88a8 or (rarely) 0x9100 - use the following command to match the ethertype:

```
 set ethernet-switching-options dot1q-tunneling ether-type 0x8100
```

EDIT:

For EX 2/3/4/3x0-series switches (pretty much anything after Junos 15), ethertypes can now be configured per-port (however the default is still 0x8100):

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 gigether-options ethernet-switch-profile tag-protocol-id 0x88a8
```

Comment: I don't. The Dot1Q tunneling is being done on a non-juniper device. The switch in question here is just acting as a transit switch. I will need to do a capture to verify current ethertype, non juniper switches will pass these frames without an issue.

Comment: ether-type is 0x8100. 

set ethernet-switching-options is not a valid command

JUNOS 20.2R3-S1.3 Also tested on vqfx-10000 with same results.